# can't execute a script via the startmenu in Gnome

Tags: gnome, scripts

I want to run structorizer on a ubuntu Gnome machine. It runs via a bash script which lives in a subfolder of my home.

Now, in order to run it I put a symlink in /usr/bin

starting the script via commandline or ALT+F2 works exactly how it should, so I know the PATH works.
However going through the 'Start Menu' (the thing you get when either pressing the Start button, oder clicking the 'Activities' on the upper left) it doesn't.

Any hint what needs to be done to make this work?

Comment: Put lines like `echo debug 1`, `echo debug 2` in the script and redirect its output to somewhere where you can read it afterwards. Is it started at all?

Comment: Describe in what sense it does not work through "Activities". In the first place, you need a `.desktop` launcher before it could appear in the Application overview (the grid with application icons). b.t.w. prefer to put your symlink under /usr/local/bin or just in "bin" or ".local/bin" in your home folder.